# No periodic orbit using Bendixon's criteria

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Using Bendixon's criteria, prove that the system
\begin{align*}
     \dot{x}_1 &= x_1x_2-x_2^4-1,\\
    \dot{x}_2 &= x_1^2-x_2^2+x_1x_2,
 \end{align*}
has not periodic orbit.

I know I have to calculate the divergence, $\nabla \cdot f = -x_2+x_1$, but $\nabla \cdot f $ is not always positive nor negative thus I cannot conclude that there is no periodic orbit, right? In other example that I did, I always get an expression that is  always positive or always negative.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: also you have a zero along the line $x_2 = x_1$.

Comment: Excuse me, I do not understand that

Comment: The Bendixon criterion requires the sign to be consistent and not be zero anywhere in the region.

Comment: You are right, but I do not know how to proceed. Maybe the dulac - bendixon criterion ?